# Unusual traffic issues on google with Tor browser

Tags: browser, tor

When you try to go to the google page and do any search, this unusual traffic message is displayed on the Tor browser screen and doesn't get out of it! I can't use the Tor browser to do google searches. Does anyone know how to solve this problem ??? because I can not do but nothing[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jdIz.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This is Google's way to tell you that if you are concerned about your privacy you should consider not to use their services in the first place.

However, when I try to do a google search over TOR I am able to proceed by solving a CAPTCHA:

[image: Google with TOR]

I guess the TOR browser suppress the CAPTCHA. Maybe it is possible to disable this behavior. However, **one way** would be to use e.g. Firefox inside a VM and route the VM's whole traffic through TOR.

**Another approach** would be to use [Startpage](https://www.startpage.com/), which claims to be ...

> the world's most private search engine.

And effectively is a *Google proxy*:

> You can’t beat Google when it comes to online search. So we’re paying
>   them to use their brilliant search results in order to remove all
>   trackers and logs. The result: The world’s best and most private
>   search engine.

Finally, why not giving an **alternative search engine** like [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com) or [searx.me](https://www.searx.me/) a go?

**EDIT:** If you have a Google account and are logged in, the message will not appear, too. Using TOR and being logged in into one of the biggest tracking and advertising networks built, is kind of contradictory as pointed out before.

Comment: Yes, mine does not show Captcha. How do I add another search engine to TOR ??

Comment: see: https://aboutdevice.com/how-to-change-the-default-search-engine-of-the-tor-browser/

Answer (score 1):

When this persists, you can bypass it by clicking the button "New Tor Circuit for this Site". You get a new IP address each time you click the button, eventually one of those IP addresses will work.

I made an extension https://gitlab.torproject.org/lansi90/google-captcha-bypass-extension that deals with this issue transparently. Since I started using it, I do not encounter these pages anymore.